# show an error while create own default constraint name in datetime datatype column

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

```
CREATE TABLE [guest].[m_WORKING_HOUR_SETTING](
    [GROUP_ID] [int] NULL,
    [WORKING_START_HOUR] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [WORKING_END_HOUR] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CREATED_TIME] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_WORKING_HOUR_SETTING_CREATED_TIME]  default (getutcdate()) ,
    [CREATED_BY] [int] NULL
) 

GO
```

When I create a table with own default constraint name for datetime datatype column. It's show an error like Incorrect syntax near the keyword `default`. I tried myself but I couldn't find the error. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Put it at the end. Look at the documentation for correct syntax.

Comment: I don't get any error your query run perfect.

Comment: Agree with @Shree. See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8eeaa). Assumed SQL Server due to brackets though.

Comment: i'm using sybase ASE 15.5

Answer (score 0):

Default is considered a constraint, I don't think you can add two constraints to a column like that.

```
CREATE TABLE m_WORKING_HOUR_SETTING(
    GROUP_ID int NULL,
    WORKING_START_HOUR varchar(10) NULL,
    WORKING_END_HOUR varchar(30) NULL,
    CREATE_TIME datetime default getutcdate() NULL,
    CREATED_BY int NULL
```

)

If you want to have a named constraint on that column that accomplishes the same thing you can create the table with no default/constraint, then create a named default and bind it to the column.

```
create default DF_WORKING_HOUR_SETTING_CREATED_TIME as getutcdate()

sp_bindefault DF_WORKING_HOUR_SETTING_CREATED_TIME, "guest.m_WORKING_HOUR_SETTING"
```

[Sybase ASE Table Creation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/X35615.htm)

[Defining Integrity Constraints for Tables](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/sqlug285.htm)

[Defaults and Null Values](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/sqlug262.htm)

[Creating Defaults](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/X66206.htm)